# Problem with standard addition

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I am working on the problem 8-23 of Skoog's textbook. In brief, a standard addition protocol is followed to determine the concentration of nitrite. In order to estimate the concentration, a colorimetric reaction is done using 1 mL of an unknown solution to which 24 mL of reagent is added before measuring the absorbance (A = 0.300). To 50.00 mL of the original solution is added 1.00 mL of a nitrite standard solution at 1 mM. The same color-forming procedure was followed and a new absorbance of 0.530 was obtained. In my opinion, the step involving the dilution of the solution with reagent (1 + 24 mL) should be ignored since it is repeated for both measurement. However, in the solution manual, the concentration 0,025 mM is corrected by multiplying by 25, so the answer given is 0.623 mM. I think the answer is wrong. What is your opinion?

Comment: Can you post the exact question in the text? Skoog has plenty of editions.

Comment: The description is too brief. If the calculation determines the concentration of added standard in the diluted solution and from that the concentration of analyte in the diluted solution, you do have to multiply by 25. You are not showing that part of the calculation, so there is no way to answer this.

Comment: The exact question is "The method of standard additions was used to determine nitrite in a soil sample. A 1.00-mL portion of the sample was mixed with 24.00 mL of a colorimetric reagent, and the nitrite was converted to a colored product that produced a blank-corrected absorbance of 0.300. To 50.00 mL of the original sample, 1.00 mL of a standard solution of 1.00E-3 M nitrite was added. The same color-forming procedure was followed, and the new absorbance was 0.530. What was the concentration of nitrite
in the original undiluted sample?" My answer is 2.49E-5 M, Skoog answer is 6.23E-4 M.

Comment: You correctly measured the concentration in the diluted sample. imagine had you used a different dilution.